# Ubuntu 19.10 - Issues with USB 2.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

**Issue:**

I want to use my USB 2.0 ports in Ubuntu 19.10, but they do not seem to work.

**What I have already tried:**

- Unplugging and plugging the peripherals (and USB drives) back in - Did not help.
- Putting the peripherals on USB 3.0 - Works, but I still want to be able to use my USB 2.0 ports
- Doing `apt dist-upgrade` - Did not help.

**Environment:**

- **CPU** - AMD FX-8350
- **MOTHERBOARD** - Gigabyte 970A-UD3 (AM3/AM3+) with BIOS version FC

Please,assist me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was **[IOMMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input-output_memory_management_unit)**. By default it is set to **DISABLED**. It needs to be set to **ENABLED**.